# Over-release under objc ARC with -Os, but not with -O0

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, llvm

I've already filed a radar (rdar://12311693, http://openradar.appspot.com/12311693) for the following issue, but I thought I'd post here as well to see if anyone can spot a mistake in my code that could lead to the crash.

The following code sample leads to a crash due to an over-release when built with compiler optimization turned on (-Os), but does not crash when compiler optimization is turned off (-O0). The project is being built with Xcode 4.4.1 (4F1003), Apple LLVM compiler 4.0

The app crashes when num2 is over-released. Enable Zombie Objects to confirm that this is the case.

```
// This crashes under -Os, but not under -O0
NSNumber *num1 = @((float)arc4random() / (float)UINT32_MAX);
NSNumber *num2 = @((float)arc4random() / (float)UINT32_MAX);

NSNumber *foo1 = num1;
NSNumber *foo2 = num2;

for (NSUInteger i=0; i<2; i++) {

    NSLog(@"foo1: %p %@", foo1, foo1);
    NSLog(@"foo2: %p %@", foo2, foo2);

    // swap foo1 and foo2
    foo1 = num2;
    foo2 = num1;
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks for filing the radar.

Comment: I use LLVM 4.0 too, under OS X lion.If I compile and run it with -OS it doesn't crash.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri Interesting. I was running on iOS 5.1 (device and simulator both crash)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compiler bug.   Thanks for filing it.

`num1` and `num2` should guarantee the lifespan of the pointed-to instances.  I suspect the optimizer is [correctly] reusing stack slots and [incorrectly] emitting a release/retain sequence that leads to the issue.

---

In response to stackmaster;   it is a compiler bug.  The whole point of ARC is to transition Objective-C to the point where the compiler can analyze the code with 100% certainty to know where to stick retains/releases such that you, the developer, don't have to.    By and large, it can achieve exactly that, even in the face of threading, as long as both all code that uses the object in the MRR world is well behaved and the developer doesn't "escape" the object out of ARC control and do something naughty.  Two big ifs, but a vast improvement over MRR.

Finally, if your code doesn't work when optimized (when no compiler bugs come into play) **it is because your code is broken**.   A properly written optimizer *does not break correctly written code*.

While some compilers are notoriously buggy, LLVM is not one of them (I won't make claims about GCC because I haven't used it in years, but I'd bet the same could be said).   An iOS or OS X system will executed millions and millions of lines of compiled **with optimization enabled** code on every boot and the system works quite well.

So, no, "the optimizer is turned on" is never the final resolution for a crash.

---

As Catfish_man noted, there are esoteric optimizer options that *will produce* technically incorrect code on purpose.  They are not enabled by -Os or other "standard" optimizations.   They are mostly centered on math operations and, thus, won't typically cause crashes as much as faster creep of error into calculations.

Comment: @stackmonster Is ARC not just a feature of the compiler?

Comment: Inserting retains and releases yes can be a feature, but a compiler bug in optimized code is not a certainty.  Not *ANYTHING* is supposed to work when you optimize code.  Its not guaranteed to work at all optimization levels.  There is plenty of code that doesnt work under optimization levels that is not a "compiler" bug.  There's no such guarantee.  When I look at the above code, ARC not doing the right thing when optimized seems like a problem, but its not with the optimizer unless the optimizer is supposed to respect ARCs constraints at all times.  I never heard anyone make those guarantees

Comment: @stackmonster: With the exception of undefined behaviour and (some) implementation-defined behaviour, the optimizer should be building code that behaves the same way (to an outside observer) as what was written. Something that causes an overrelease in the posted code is definitely a bug.

Comment: @stackmonster that's simply wrong what you wrote. Optimization is not an excuse.

Comment: its not wrong tons of code doesnt work under optimization, if ARC is supposed to then I guess it should be fixed.(?) who cares? not me

Comment: @stackmonster If your code breaks with optimization turned on, you might want to start working on your code. Especially if "tons" of it break.

Comment: THere are no guarantees that optimization in ANY C compiler on this EARTH will not break your code.

Comment: If you're not relying on undefined behavior, then optimizations that break your program are incorrect optimizations. If you're relying on undefined behavior, your program is incorrect. Of course, some optimizations are intentionally incorrect (some of the stuff turned on by -ffast-math for example), but those aren't on by default.